# Mask svg images don't show on explorer and edge

Tags: html, css

I try to display a svg icon on a html page.
On chrome and other browser that works fine but on edge and internet explorer the icon don't appear.
I made it witk mask in css.

```
body{ 
  background: #000;
}
.default {
  background-color: #fff;
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
}
.icon {
  mask:url('./icons/network.svg') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-mask: url('./icons/network.svg') no-repeat center center;
  mask-size:90px auto;
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Icons</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <image  class="default icon"></image >
  </body>
</html>
```

On internet explorer it displays a white square ( i think is the default class in css).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com) Internet Explorer does not support mask at all and edge only partially supports this feature. Have a look here: https://caniuse.com/#search=mask